# Cannot find a way to get the parameterized type on a method parameter of a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need the ability to find the parameterized type of a method parameter on a Spring bean.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1.

I have a Spring bean that looks like the following:

```java
public class MyBean {
   public void doFoo(List<Integer> param) {...}
}
```

I need to be able to find out the parameterized type on the `param` parameter.  Normally I could just do this:

```java
MyBean myBean = getMyBean();

ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)myBean
   .getClass()
   .getMethod("doFoo", List.class)
   .getGenericParameterTypes()[0];

Class<?> listOfX = (Class<?>)pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

However, when doing this against a Spring bean, the `getGenericParameterTypes()` method always returns an array of `Class` objects instead of an array of `Type` objects.

The reason for this is that Spring uses CGLIB extensively to provide runtime-recompilation of classes to support AOP.  So instead of getting an instance of `MyBean`, I instead get an instance of `MyBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$xxxxxxxx`, and that "recompiled" class loses all generics information (apparently because CGLIB was written before generics existed and is no longer actively supported?).

I could use some ideas on how I might be able to get to the parameterized information on this parameter if given nothing more that a Spring bean instance.  I've been trying to look for ways to get access to the `MyBean.class` from `MyBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$xxxxxxxx` and from there be able to find the real method that I can use reflection against.  But I haven't found a solution yet.  I'm trying to avoid `Class.forName(...)` at all costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following code works in my particular case to find the underlying real class:

```java
if (myBean instanceof org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised) {
    Class<?> realClass = ((Advised)r).getTargetClass();
}
```

From there I can use standard reflection.  But I'm not sure how kosher this solution is or whether I can expect all Spring beans to implement the `Advised` interface.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to implement BeanPostProcessor.
You can get access to underlying class before bean initialization.

Here example:

```java
@Component
public class ParametrizedBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // bean is your actual class
        try {
            if ("myBean".equals(beanName)) {
                ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) bean
                        .getClass()
                        .getMethod("doFoo", List.class)
                        .getGenericParameterTypes()[0];

                Class<?> listOfX = (Class<?>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                System.out.println(listOfX); //class java.lang.Integer
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // bean is proxy object
        return bean;
    }
}
```